# Convert json file with nested dictionaries in one column to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json file with the below structure:

```
[{
"field1": "first",
"field2": "d",
"id": 35,
"features": [
    {
        "feature_id": 2,
        "value": 6
    },
    {
        "feature_id": 3,
        "value": 8.5
    },
    {
      "feature_id":5,
      "value":6.7
    },
    {
    "feature_id":10,
    "value": 3.4
    }
  ],
  "time": "2018-11-17"
},
{
"field1": "second",
"field2": "b",
"id": 36,
"features": [
    {
        "feature_id": 3,
        "value": 5.4
    },
    {
        "feature_id": 10,
        "value": 9.5
    },

  ],
  "time": "2018-11-17"
}]
```

I can change this to Pandas Dataframe

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open(file) as json_data:
 data = json.load(json_data)

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

but one column has a nested dictionary in a list and therefore the features column contains the column with the list of dictionaries. I want to flatten my whole data so the final table should look like this. Appreciate any help?

[Final_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gylok.png)

Comment: Your json file is not valid json syntax, so that seems to likely be a reason that it doesn't work. If you have a list of items it should be inside `[ ]` separated by commas for json. Also please show the current format of the data/DataFrame and why that is not correct.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit it to be inside a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json is chnaged with `[]` for valid:

```
data = [{
"field1": "first",
"field2": "d",
"id": 35,
"features": [
    {
        "feature_id": 2,
        "value": 6
    },
    {
        "feature_id": 3,
        "value": 8.5
    },
    {
      "feature_id":5,
      "value":6.7
    },
    {
    "feature_id":10,
    "value": 3.4
    }
  ],
  "time": "2018-11-17"
},
{
"field1": "second",
"field2": "b",
"id": 36,
"features": [
    {
        "feature_id": 3,
        "value": 5.4
    },
    {
        "feature_id": 10,
        "value": 9.5
    },

  ],
  "time": "2018-11-17"
}]
```

Then loop each item and for `features` create new items of dictioanries, last pass is to `DataFrame` contructor:

```
L = []
for x in data:
    d = {}
    for k, v in x.items():
        if k == 'features':
            for y in v:
                d[f"feature_id_{y['feature_id']}"] = y['value']
        else:
            d[k] = v
    L.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
   feature_id_10  feature_id_2  feature_id_3  feature_id_5  field1 field2  id  \
0            3.4           6.0           8.5           6.7   first      d  35   
1            9.5           NaN           5.4           NaN  second      b  36   

         time  
0  2018-11-17  
1  2018-11-17
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, can you explain the meaning of **f** in this line of the code before "feature_id_{y['feature_id']}"

   `d[f"feature_id_{y['feature_id']}"] = y['value']`

Comment: @John - it create dictionary by [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) - each value of nested dictionaries in list convert to new one.

Answer (score 1):

For flatten JSON object with nested keys into single Dict, use the below function.

```
def flatten_json(nested_json):
"""
    Flatten json object with nested keys into a single level.
    Args:
        nested_json: A nested json object.
    Returns:
        The flattened json object if successful, None otherwise.
"""
out = {}

def flatten(x, name=''):
    if type(x) is dict:
        for a in x:
            flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
    elif type(x) is list:
        i = 0
        for a in x:
            flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
            i += 1
    else:
        out[name[:-1]] = x

flatten(nested_json)
return out
```

Hope this function will help you.